# Batch - How do I call a variable with another variable?

Tags: batch-file

In batch I'm trying to make a program that will search a directory for files with a specific extension then display them, and allow you to delete certain ones. The way that I have thought of going about this is to have the user type in the number of the item in the array list. so I have this code:

```
@echo off

set counter=0
set counter2=0

setlocal enableextensions
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:menu
cls
echo.
echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
----------------------------
echo.
echo ----------------------------------------Search By File Type------------ 
----------------------------
echo.
echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
----------------------------

set /p inputE= Please type the file extension (ex, txt): 
set /p inputP= Please enter location to search (ex, C:\): 



for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ( 
    'where /r %inputP% *.%inputE%' 
) do ( 
    echo !counter! - %%a
    set file!counter!=%%a
    set /a counter+=1
)

set fileDel=file!counter!
echo !%fileDel%!

pause
```

and the last 2 lines are the test for my method, but it doesn't work. When i run it and the program gets to that part it should display the last file location a second time, but it says echo is off. Any way to do this properly? Any other way to accomplish the same goal? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lets say there are three files that are found. You assign file1, file2 and file3 and then you assign fileDel=file4 but file4 has no value because it wasn't assigned in the loop.  Then when you echo fileDel you are echoing nothing but if you type echo with no arguments it just says "ECHO is off"

Comment: i feel like an idiot now... thanks for the help :) @JerryJeremiah

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how were you going to choose which file to delete?  Oh, I see, the loop prints the options for the user.  That's cool.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah thanks, I'm making a little tool to help in Cyber Patriots

Comment: Your counter has to be immediately incremented as the first command in the `DO` portion of the `FOR` command. But in regards to your last two lines of code, you do not need delayed expansion for the counter variable. If the counter was set correctly in your `FOR` command the last `SET` command should just be: `set fileDel=!file%counter%!` and then `echo %fileDel%`